# Select from a database and insert into a different database in PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have to select data from a table in a database and insert them into another table in a different database but its not working.Could you please correct the code and let me know your response?

```
<?php
$log1  = "taxicom";
$pwd1 = "************";
$db1 = "ussd";    
global $mysqli1;

$log2  = "Taxicom";
$pwd2 = "******";
$db2 = "suitecrm";
global $mysqli2;

$mysqli1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", $log1, $pwd1, $db1);
$mysqli2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", $log2, $pwd2, $db2);

$quer = mysqli_query($mysqli1 ,"SELECT  DISTINCT numdest,id,operateur,mont_pay FROM rapport GROUP BY numdest ORDER BY id ");


  while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($quer)){
      $variable1 = $data['numdest'];
      $variable2 = $data['id'];
      $variable3 = $data['operateur'];
      $variable4 = $data['mont_pay'];      

  $quer2=mysqli_query($mysqli2,"INSERT INTO prospects (id_client_source,num_tel_dest,operateur,montant) VALUES(' $variable2',' $variable1',' $variable3',' $variable4')" );
 if($quer){
    echo"Inséré <br>";
    }else{
        echo "non inséré <br>";
    }}
var_dump($quer2);

set_time_limit(500);

?>
```

Comment: Can you expand upon "not working", errors, no inserted data...?

Comment: yes, data is not inserted.

Comment: In your while loop, use $data = mysqli_fetch_object($quer) instead of $data = mysql_fetch_object($quer).

Comment: Can you test (echo them out) $variable1 though 4 to confirm they are populated?

Comment: after correcting the mysqli, he said he is inserted, but in the database is not inserted

Comment: I did echo then out and they are populated

Comment: you are mixing two api: mysqli and mysql. You are using mysql api in this line:  `while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($quer)){` while in the rest of the code you are using mysql. Please fix that in your code

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do the operation in one single query by prefixing the tables with the relevant database name like:

```
insert into `suitecrm`.`prospects` ( 
    `id_client_source`,
    `num_tel_dest`,
    `operateur`,
    `montant`
)
select distinct `id`, `numdest`, `operateur`, `mont_pay` 
    from `ussd`.`rapport` 
    group by numdest 
    order by id;
```

Comment: but i have two databases !

Comment: the db name prefixes the table name above - one db is called `ussd` and the other is `suitecrm` ~ presumably on the same server??

Answer (score 0):

With my sql you can do this with a single query

```
"INSERT INTO database1.prospects (id_client_source,num_tel_dest,operateur,montant)
 SELECT  DISTINCT id, numdest,operateur,mont_pay 
 FROM database2.rapport;"
```

And you don't use aggregation functio so you don'need the group by clause
Moreover that you use disctint too. 
and  ordering for an a insert i unuseful  so you can omit the order by clause

If your user $log2 has the right for select from db1 you can use a single mysqli_query

```
$quer2=mysqli_query($mysqli2,
    "INSERT INTO database1.prospects (id_client_source,num_tel_dest,operateur,montant)
    SELECT  DISTINCT id, numdest,operateur,mont_pay 
    FROM database2.rapport;" );
```

if the user have not the right
Try using msqli_fetch_object and, inside while loop,  test for $quer2 not for quer  and if not insert look at the error

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_object($quer)){
      $variable1 = $data['numdest'];
      $variable2 = $data['id'];
      $variable3 = $data['operateur'];
      $variable4 = $data['mont_pay'];      

  $quer2 = mysqli_query($mysqli2,"INSERT INTO prospects (id_client_source,num_tel_dest,operateur,montant) VALUES(' $variable2',' $variable1',' $variable3',' $variable4')" );
 if($quer2 ){
    echo"Inséré <br>";
    }else{
        echo "non inséré <br>";
        die(mysqli_error($mysqli2));
    }
}


var_dump($quer2);

set_time_limit(500);
```

Comment: If the two database are on the same server you can use the query in the same way  .. i have update the answer

Comment: your user $logs2 has the right to select from db1 database?  i have update the answer

Comment: No the user $log2 has not the right to select from db1 database.